# pull up image search results from the web and display images

Tags: javascript, python, google-custom-search

I am not sure the best way to do this.

I will be displaying a set of words, for example "hampster, cat, baby, smile, fun"; when they click on one I want to pull the first 5 or so images from Google Images (or any reliable image repository) using that word as search criteria and display them on the page.

I see the google image search API has been discontinued and I am not sure if the google-custom-search is what I want as that pulls up the images on a new google search results window where I want JUST the images and displayed on the same page right below where they clicked.

The purpose of the site is to give the user visual hints of the translation of the word and not just give the translation so they will visually associate the word and learn the words better.